# How to prevent firefox from autofilling username input with e-mail?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firefox, autocomplete

I'm using React.
I have a registration form component with *Username*, *E-mail* and *Password* fields on it. I've set `autoComplete="off"` for the entire form, but firefox still trying to autocomplete the form.
I think this second autocomplete feature is somehow built in browser itself, so i don't think it will be possible to disable it completely from my code.

I've accepted this, but there is another issue. Firefox is trying to fill Username field on the form with E-mail. When i delete Username field autofill switches to E-mail field and works fine, but i dont want to delete Username field. Also, if i rename Username field (both 'name' and 'label' props) to something completely different from 'Username' it works too.

Question: how can i prevent Firefox from filling the wrong field?

Here's E-mail and Username components:

```js
<FormRow>
    <InputText name="username" label="Username" rules={{ required: true }} />
</FormRow>
<FormRow>
    <InputText name="email" label="E-mail" rules={{ required: true }} />
</FormRow>
```

Props `name` goes to `input` element.
Props `label` renders in `label` element.

Thank you!

Comment: have you add autoComplete="off" to every <InputText /> component instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to turn autocomplete off.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: he already did that